# $observer->getLayout()->getUpdate()->addHandle not work (AlgoliaSearch module)

Tags: magento2, layout, event-observer

I trying to install module AlgoliaSearch and its not working. So I began to explore its code and there is Observer where xml layout should be overwritten

```
 class Observer implements ObserverInterface
{
protected $config;
protected $product_helper;
protected $helper;

public function __construct(ConfigHelper $configHelper)
{
    $this->config = $configHelper;
}

public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{
    if ($this->config->isEnabledFrontEnd()) {
        if ($this->config->getApplicationID() && $this->config->getAPIKey()) {
            if ($this->config->isPopupEnabled() || $this->config->isInstantEnabled()) {
                $observer->getLayout()->getUpdate()->addHandle('algolia_search_handle');

                if ($this->config->isDefaultSelector()) {
                    $observer->getLayout()->getUpdate()->addHandle('algolia_search_handle_with_topsearch');
                } else {
                    $observer->getLayout()->getUpdate()->addHandle('algolia_search_handle_no_topsearch');
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

I printed some test strings in observer to check that it is executed, but xml layout is not overwritten. Why is that?

Here is \etc\frontend\events.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
<event name="layout_load_before">
    <observer name="algolia_injection" instance="Algolia\AlgoliaSearch\Model\Observer" />
</event>
```

I added var_dump to vendor\magento\framework\View\Result\Layout.php addHandle() function

```
 public function addHandle($handleName)
{   var_dump( $handleName);
    $this->getLayout()->getUpdate()->addHandle($handleName);
    return $this;
}
```

Modules layouts did not show up

Comment: which event? If you don't know it, check `etc/events.xml` of the module

Comment: It's layout_load_before

Comment: I added events.xml to question

Comment: And with your test strings you checked if all the nested if conditions are true, i.e. `addHandle()` is actually called? Or just if the observer itself is called?

Comment: Yes,  "if" conditions are executed.

Comment: I added var_dump($handleName) to vendor\magento\framework\View\Result\Layout.php addHandle() function - modules layouts did not show up

Comment: Then I have no idea, this should work. Probably there is a bug somewhere else in the module, for ex. that the handles are not defined properly.